# MySQL: How to do daily reports?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Assume I have a log of something. Each record has a timestamp (MySQL data type TIMESTAMP) in the format `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (from PHP). I need to produce a report that looks like this:

```
===========================================
| Date                  | Total Sales     |
===========================================
| Thursday, Dec 1, 2011 | 100             |
-------------------------------------------
| Friday, Dec 2, 2011   | 200             |
-------------------------------------------
| Saturday, Dec 3, 2011 | 150             |
-------------------------------------------
... and so on ...
```

I assume I have to dynamically build the SQL from PHP, which is OK. I'm just not sure what the SQL would look like. Ideas?

Comment: What ideas do you have in mind (which you are unsure about)?

Comment: BTW: "timestamp" is *not* an appropriate format for "date and time". If at all possible, you should use "datetime" instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How to count the number of records per day

This is what I originally thought you wanted. I'm leaving it here because it might be useful to other people.

You have a bunch of timestamps. You want to group them by individual days and get the number of records per day.

Assuming your timestamp field is named `ts`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DAY(ts), MONTH(ts), YEAR(ts) FROM tableName
       GROUP BY YEAR(ts), MONTH(ts), DAY(ts);
```

### How to generate daily reports for individual people

Ok this is what you really wanted. Let's draw a sample table with some records:

```
ts                      person         sales
2011-12-01 10:00:00     John           10
2011-12-01 10:30:00     Mary           25
2011-12-01 11:00:00     John           20
2011-12-02 14:00:00     John           40
```

To get the daily totals for a particular person, you would do:

```
SELECT SUM(sales), DAY(ts), MONTH(ts), YEAR(ts) FROM tableName
       WHERE person='John'
       GROUP BY YEAR(ts), MONTH(ts), DAY(ts);
```

This is selecting records where `person` is John, grouped by unique days, and summing the `sales` value for those records. If you want reports for every person combined, just remove the `WHERE` clause.

### Final note

You can simplify your SQL a little bit if you use the `DATE` type instead of the `DATETIME` type. I'm selecting and grouping by the day, month and year which I need to get using three separate functions. If you're using the `DATE` type, calling these functions would be unnecessary and I could just select and group by `ts` directly. It's up to you how you want to represent your data.

Comment: Anson, I'm not interested in the count for each day. The "Total Something" column could be, say, total sales for that day. Or could be the total hours logged by an employee for that day. The second column is not so important. I need to know how to get the timestamp and group them by days and then convert them to something more "human readable".

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, so to clarify, if John logged 50 sales on Dec 1, and Mary logged 50 sales on Dec 1 as well (in other words, two separate records having the same date in your database), your PHP page should generate one row with 100 being the total sales for Jan 1?

Comment: This would be an individual report. So, the report would only be for John or only for Mary. But I guess it could be a collective number of people. My confusion is how to get those individual records, group them by day, and represent each day as "Thursday, Jan 1, 2011" etc.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Once you get the day, month and year in numerical format, you can construct a date stamp and pass it to PHP's **[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** function to turn it into a more human-readable string.